# Gradle: configure sub-project (module) from parent build script

Tags: gradle, module, configuration, parent, subproject

I split my project onto modules/sub-projects following this guide:

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html

In the main script `build.gradle` i apply the configuration for the sub-projects:

```
subprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }
}
```

And this works fine if i run the subproject build from the root build directory:

```
mainProject$ ./gradlew clean :common:build
```

(successfully builds `:common` module)

BUT i want to be able to build the `:common` module being in `common` directory:

```
mainProject$ cd common
common$ ./gradlew clean build
```

This fails if the *repositories* are not configured explicitly in `common/build.gradle` file. But i did it already in the parent config above and i'd like the subprojects pick-up parent config where it's possible.

So, hot to configure parent project and sub-projects so when i run a subproject build from the subproject directory, it considers parent configuration as well (and not only repositories configuration, but also some constants, dependencies and so on).

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in child `settings.gradle`: sub-projects should not have this file, otherwise gradle considers current directory as a root project!

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sub:project_locations

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:initialization

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you should not have gradle wrapper scripts installed in each subprojects directories, but instead keep only one gradle wrapper installed in the root project directory. 
Then if you want to invoke build from subprojects directories you will have to reference gradlew script from parent directories : this is explained in one note in the Wrapper documentation : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:using_wrapper

There is also a reference to this in another page in official doc:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html#sec:executing_a_multiproject_build

> There’s one last thing to note. When you’re using the Gradle wrapper, the first approach doesn’t work well because you have to specify the path to the wrapper script if you’re not in the project root. For example, if you’re in the webservice subproject directory, you would have to run ../../gradlew build.

When executing build from a subproject directory, Gradle will automatically search for root project configuration, as you expected: this is done during the initialization phase (see here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:initialization)